# redirect to another page clicking on dropdown listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here in the given code, my primary purpose is to redirect to another page by clicking on the button according to the drop-down selected. Here first form is for countries and second listing is for selected products according to the country. Now I want to redirect to the page as the key matching to value by clicking the button. Here is the example of it. https://cibtvisas.com/

*HTML Code*,

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                          <div class="search-category-container">
                            <label class="styled-select">
      <select name="dep" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>Australia</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>UK</option>
      </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                          <div class="search-category-container">
                            <label class="styled-select">
      <select name="cname" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
        <option>Contact name</option>
      </select>
       </label> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
                          <button type="submit" name="clickon"  class="btn btn-search-icon"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
    </form>
```

*jquery code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$department = $("select[name='dep']");
$cname = $("select[name='cname']");
$clickbutton = $("select[name='clickon']")

$department.click(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "Select") 
{
$("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
$("<option>Visa name</option>").appendTo($cname);
}

if ($(this).val() == "Australia") {
$("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
$("<option value='Australia_temporary'>Australia Temporary Graduate Visa (Post..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_skilled'>Australia Skilled Independent Visa (subclass 189)</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_srvg'>Australia SRGV Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='australia_family'>Australia Family Immigration</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='partner_skills'>Partner Skills Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='australia_nominated'>Australia Skilled Nominated Visa (subclass 190)</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_employer'>Australia Employer Nomination Scheme (ENS)</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_subclass'>Australia Subclass 457 Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_business'>Australia Business Innovation & Investment..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_student'>Australia Student Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_doctors'>Australia Doctors & Nurses Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_immigration'>Australia Immigration Skills Assessment</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_talent'>Australia Business Talent..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Contributory_parents'>Contributory Parents Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_child'>Australia Child Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_graduate'>Australia Temporary Graduate Visa..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_regional'>Australia Skilled Regional (Provisional) Visa ..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_recognised'>Australia Skilled Recognised Graduate ...</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_resident'>Australia Resident Return Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_evaluation'>Australia Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_partner'>Australia Partner Immigration</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='DIBP'>DIBP</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Partner_skills'>Partner Skills Assessment</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_innovation'>Australia Business Innovation & Investment..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Visa_documentation'>Visa Documentation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_parents'>Australia Parents Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_ens'>Australia ENS Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='DIBP_evaluation'>DIBP Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Contributory_visa'>Contributory Parents Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Australia_investment'>Australia Business Innovation & Investment..</option>").appendTo($cname);
}

if ($(this).val() == "Canada") 
{
$("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
$("<option value='Canada_family'>Canada Family Immigration</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_quebec_skilled'>Canada Quebec Skilled Worker Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Quebec_evaluation'>Quebec Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='CIC_guidance'>CIC Guidance (Post ITA)</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_dependent_work'>Canada Dependent Work Permit</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_self'>Canada Self Employed Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_manitoba'>Canada Manitoba Provincial Nomination Program</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_nova'>Canada Nova Scotia Nomination Program</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_experience'>Canada Experience Class Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_quebec_experience'>Canada Quebec Experience Class</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_parent'>Canada Parent And Grandparent Super Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_self_employed'>Canada Self Employed Visa Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Saskatchewan_nomination'>Saskatchewan Nomination Program Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_dependent'>Canada Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Atlantic_immigration'>Atlantic Immigration Pilot Program</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_federal'>Canada Federal Skilled Worker</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_fsw'>Canada FSW Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_start_up'>Canada Start_up Visa Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_business_visa'>Canada Business Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_post_graduate'>Canada Post Graduate Work Permit</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_open_work'>Canada Open Work Permit</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_start_up'>Canada Start_up Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_nova'>Canada Nova Scotia Nomination Program..</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_experience'>Canada Experience Class</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_federal'>Canada Federal Trade Worker Class</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_Manitoba_pnp'>Canada Manitoba PNP Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Saskatchewan_nomination'>Saskatchewan Nomination Program</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_work'>Canada Work Permit</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Canada_federal_trade'>Canada Federal Trade Worker Class Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Atlantic_immigration_pilot'>Atlantic Immigration Pilot Program</option>").appendTo($cname);
}

if ($(this).val() == "UK") 
{
$("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
$("<option value='UK_dependent'>UK Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='UK_tier_dependent'>UK Tier 1 Dependent</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='HSW_extensions'>UK Tier 1 / HSW Extensions Or FLR</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='FLRUK_tier'>UK Tier 1 / HSW Extensions Or FLRUK Tier 1 / HSW Extensions Or FLR</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='UK_student_dependent'>UK Student Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='UK_domestic_worker'>UK Domestic Worker Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Student_visa_general'>UK Tier 4 Student Visa General</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='UK_EEA_family'>UK EEA Family Permit</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Work_permits'>UK Tier 2 Work Permits</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Sole_representative'>UK Sole Representative Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Tier_2_dependent_visa'>UK Tier 2 Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
$("<option value='Entrepreneur_visa'>UK Tier 1 Entrepreneur Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
}

});
});


var dictionary = {
                  'Australia_temporary': 'australia-temporary-graduate-visa-(post-study-work-stream).php',
'Australia_skilled': 'Australia-skilled-independent-visa-(subclass-189).php',
'Australia_srvg': 'Australia-srvg-evaluation.php',
'australia_family': 'australia-family-immigration.php',
'partner_skills': 'partner-skills-evaluation-report.php',
'australia_nominated': 'australia-skilled-nominated-visa-(subclass-190).php',
'Australia_employer': 'australia-employer-nomination-scheme-(ens).php',
'Australia_subclass': 'australia-subclass-457-visa.php',
'Australia_business': 'australia-business-innovation-investment-(permanent)-(subclass-888-visa).php',
'Australia_student': 'australia-student-dependent-visa.php',
'Australia_doctors': 'australia-doctors-nurses-visa.php',
'Australia_immigration': 'australia-immigration-skills-assessment.php',
'Australia_talent': 'australia-business-talent-(permanent)-(subclass-132)-visa.php',
'Contributory_parents': 'contributory-parents-visa.php',
'Australia_child': 'australia-child-visa.php',
'Australia_graduate': 'australia-temporary-graduate-visa-(graduate-work-stream).php',
'Australia_regional': 'australia-skilled-regional-(provisional)-visa-(subclass-489).php',
'Australia_recognised': 'australia-skilled-recognised-graduate-(temporary)-visa-(subclass-476).php',
'Australia_resident': 'australia-resident-return-visa.php',
'Australia_evaluation': 'australia-evaluation-report.php',
'Australia_partner': 'australia-partner-immigration.php',
'DIBP': 'dibp.php',
'Partner_skills': 'partner-skills-assessment.php',
'Australia_innovation': 'australia-business-innovation-investment-(provisional)-(subclass-188-visass).php',
'Visa_documentation': 'visa-documentation.php',
'Australia_parents': 'australia-business-innovation-investment-(provisional)-(subclass-188-visas).php',
'Australia_ens': 'australia-ens-report.php',
'DIBP_evaluation': 'dibp-evaluation-report.php',
'Contributory_visa': 'contributory-parents-visas.php',

'Canada_family': 'canada-family-immigration.php',
'Canada_quebec_skilled': 'canada-quebec-skilled-worker-visa.php',
'Quebec_evaluation': 'quebec-evaluation-report.php',
'CIC_guidance': 'cic-guidance-(post-ita).php',
'Canada_dependent_work': 'canada-dependent-work-permit.php',
'Canada_self': 'canada-employed-visa.php',
'Canada_manitoba': 'canada-manitoba-provincial-nomination-program.php',
'Canada_nova': 'canada-nova-scotia-nomination-program.php',
'Canada_experience': 'canada-experience-evaluation.php',
'Canada_quebec_experience': 'canada-quebec-experience.php',
'Canada_parent': 'canada-parent-and-grandparent-visa.php',
'Canada_self_employed': 'canada-employed-visa-evaluation-report.php',
'Saskatchewan_nomination': 'saskatchewan-nomination-program-evaluation.php',
'Canada_dependent': 'canada-dependent-visa.php',
'Atlantic_immigration': 'atlantic-immigration-pilot-program.php',
'Canada_federal': 'canada-federal-skilled-worker.php',
'Canada_fsw': 'canada-fsw-evaluation.php',
'Canada_start_up': 'Canadastart-up.php',
'Canada_business_visa': 'canada-business-visa.php',
'Canada_post_graduate': 'canada-post-graduate-work-permit.php',
'Canada_open_work': 'canada-open-work-permit.php',
'Canada_start_up': 'Canadastart-upvisa.php',
'Canada_nova': 'canada-nova-scotia-nomination-program-evaluation.php',
'Canada_experience': 'canada-experience.php',
'Canada_federal': 'canada-federal-trade-worker.php',
'Canada_Manitoba_pnp': 'canada-manitoba-pnp-evaluation.php',
'Saskatchewan_nomination': 'saskatchewan-nomination-program.php',
'Canada_work': 'canada-work-permit.php',
'Canada_federal_trade': 'canada-federal-trade-worker-evaluation.php',
'Atlantic_immigration_pilot': 'atlantic-immigration-pilot-program.php',


'UK_dependent': 'uk-dependent-visa.php',
'UK_tier_dependent': 'uk-tier-1-dependent.php',
'HSW_extensions': 'uk-tier-1-hsw-extensions-or-flr.php',
'FLRUK_tier': 'uk-tier-5-youth-mobility-scheme.php',
'UK_student_dependent': 'uk-student-dependent-visa.php',
'UK_domestic_worker': 'uk-domestic-worker-visa.php',
'Student_visa_general': 'uk-tier-4-student-visa-general.php',
'UK_EEA_family': 'uk-eea-family-permit.php',
'Work_permits': 'uk-tier-2-work-permits.php',
'Sole_representative': 'uk-sole-representative-visa.php',
'Tier_2_dependent_visa': 'uk-tier-2-dependent-visa.php',
'Entrepreneur_visa': 'uk-tier-1-entrepreneur-visa.php'

};


$('form').submit(function() {
    var newaction = $('[name=cname]').val();
debugger;
    window.location.href = dictionary[newaction];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, however you firstly need to use the `change` event, not `click`, for detecting the selection changes in the `select` element. Secondly you need to stop the form submission in order for your `window.location.href` assignment to be completed. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $department = $("select[name='dep']");
  $cname = $("select[name='cname']");
  $clickbutton = $("select[name='clickon']")

  $department.change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Select") {
      $("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
      $("<option>Visa name</option>").appendTo($cname);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Australia") {
      $("select[name='cname']").empty();
      $("<option value='Australia_temporary'>Australia Temporary Graduate Visa (Post..</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='Australia_skilled'>Australia Skilled Independent Visa (subclass 189)</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='Australia_srvg'>Australia SRGV Evaluation</option>").appendTo($cname);
      // more options...
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Canada") {
      $("select[name='cname']").empty();
      $("<option value='Canada_family'>Canada Family Immigration</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='Canada_quebec_skilled'>Canada Quebec Skilled Worker Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='Quebec_evaluation'>Quebec Evaluation Report</option>").appendTo($cname);
      // more options...
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "UK") {
      $("select[name='cname']").empty();
      $("<option value='UK_dependent'>UK Dependent Visa</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='UK_tier_dependent'>UK Tier 1 Dependent</option>").appendTo($cname);
      $("<option value='HSW_extensions'>UK Tier 1 / HSW Extensions Or FLR</option>").appendTo($cname);
      // more options...
    }

  });
});


var dictionary = {
  'Australia_temporary': 'australia-temporary-graduate-visa-(post-study-work-stream).php',
  'Australia_skilled': 'Australia-skilled-independent-visa-(subclass-189).php',
  'Australia_srvg': 'Australia-srvg-evaluation.php',
  'australia_family': 'australia-family-immigration.php',
   // more options...

  'Canada_family': 'canada-family-immigration.php',
  'Canada_quebec_skilled': 'canada-quebec-skilled-worker-visa.php',
  'Quebec_evaluation': 'quebec-evaluation-report.php',
   // more options...

  'UK_dependent': 'uk-dependent-visa.php',
  'UK_tier_dependent': 'uk-tier-1-dependent.php',
  'HSW_extensions': 'uk-tier-1-hsw-extensions-or-flr.php',
  // more options...
};

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newaction = $('[name=cname]').val();
  debugger;
  //window.location.href = dictionary[newaction]dictionary[newaction];
  console.log(dictionary[newaction]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="search-category-container">
        <label class="styled-select">
          <select name="dep" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>Australia</option>
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>UK</option>
          </select>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
      <div class="search-category-container">
        <label class="styled-select">
          <select name="cname" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
            <option>Contact name</option>
          </select>
           </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
      <button type="submit" name="clickon" class="btn btn-search-icon"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'd also suggest you look in to AJAX to retrieve the data for the `option` elements, as your current logic ties the JS very tightly to the data you're managing, plus it adds a lot of client-side bloat and isn't very DRY.